# Powershell script to find task scheduler issues

Tags: email, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to write a powershell script to look at a server's task scheduler logs for a specific task, and I want to know if there are any errors or anything out of the ordinary.

I typically see event IDs below so I want to basically send an email if there's something not in this list (meaning something else happened that I need to look at):

107 - Task triggered on scheduler
100 - Task started
129 - Created Task Process
100 - Task Started
200 - Action started
201 - Action completed
102 - Task completed

So in my head I want to look for event IDs that are not any of the above, for a task named "Batch001".

If I another code appears, then send me an email. I have the email PS code working fine, but I need to figure out the searching, filtering and then triggering of the email code.

Below is what I have. It essentially looks at the logs and writes (appends) the corresponding events to a text file - kind of an audit log. If there is an issue contacting the server, then it writes a message to an error text file and emails that content to me via Office 365.

What I cannot get this thing to do is to email on warnings. I try testing this out by starting a batch job and then while it's running, have the schedule try to start another one. I get a warning that it cannot launch the task because there is another instance running - code 322. This event could be because a batch is running too long and I want this captured and emailed.

Essentially, anything out of the ordinary, I want to get an email. If I can't figure out warnings, I can't figure out a way to write all the stuff to a text file but create a case/try/catch to ignore the codes at the beginning of the email.

Script I have:

Start-Transcript -Path "C:\BatchLogs\BatchTranscripts.txt"
$task_name = "Batch001"
$file = "C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt"
$file_path = Test-Path $file
$pc = $_

#If file hasn't been created, create it
If ($file_path -ne $true){
New-Item C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt
}
#Filter xml to pull task scheduler events
try {
invoke-command -ComputerName "servername.domain" -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
try {
$events = @(
Get-WinEvent  -FilterXml @'



*[EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']='\Batch001'] and *[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 86400000]]]



'@  -ErrorAction Stop
)
}
catch {
Write-Warning -Message "Failed to query $($env:computername) because $($_.Exception.Message)" *> "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt"
Get-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt" | Add-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt"

```
 [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
 $EmailTo = "me@domain.com"
 $EmailFrom = "me@domain.com"
 $Subject = "Batch001 Failure"
 $Body = Get-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt"
 $SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
 $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
 $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
 $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
 $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@domain.com", "Password123");
 $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

}
if ($events) {
$events | Select MachineName,TimeCreated,Id,TaskDisplayName |  Out-File -Append C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt
}
} # end of scriptblock
} catch {
Write-Warning -Message "Failed to contact $pc because $($_.Exception.Message)" *> "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt"
Get-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt" | Add-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt"

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$EmailTo = "me@domain.com"
$EmailFrom = "me@domain.com"
$Subject = "Batch001 Failure"
$Body = Get-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@domain.com", "Password123");
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)

}

Stop-Transcript

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @DawgFather .... See if this helps you get closer to getting something tested script/command wise for the data you need. Then, [edit] your question, and then add in the logic you try that is not working for your need.